# python: check a variable has value in it

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to python and working with while loop. I have a scenario that, I need to check whether a variable has a value or string associated with it and to find this I should not use built-in functions in python. I tried using the below in while loop, but its throwing error as shown:

Code:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,"string1", "string2"]

print ("Test of List")

i = 0

while (li[i] != ""):
    print (li[i])
    i = i + 1

print ("Val of i :",i)
```

Output:

```
Test of List

1

2

3

4

5

string1

string2

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sesubra2\Desktop\python_codes.py", line 71, in <module>

    while (li[i] != ""):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: No item in your list is equal to `""`, so you keep incrementing `i` until you reach the end of your list, then you still try to access the list, and get an `IndexError`

Comment: Looks like XY-Problem. What is your goal? If you want to iterate over a list, just do ``for i in li:``.

Comment: Break your while loop once I value reaches the length your list.

Comment: i am trying to get the number of items in list without using in-built functions

Comment: @Senthilkumar I wrote a simple code to avoid this error in answer.

Comment: @Senthilkumar why? Also, this is kinda like trying to swim without touching water, but ok, I'll update my answer

Comment: @Senthilkumar Take a look...

Answer (score 2):

I improved your code to avoid the error. (It works):

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,"string1", "string2"]

for i in range(len(li)):
    print(li[i])
```

Or:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,"string1", "string2"]

for element in li:
    print(element)
```

Comment: Because this is an antipattern. The proper code is `for item in li: print item`.

Comment: First, there is no need to set lower range boundary to ``0`` since it is always zero if not given. Second, there is no need to use ``range()``to iterate over a list.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  The reward is not an answer that solves questioner's problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using while the wrong way, i.e. to check conditions. Instead use while to loop through the list and inside it, use an if condition for checking. After completing the if, increment i outside the if statement.

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,"string1", "string2"]

print ("Test of List")

i = 0

while i<len(li):
    if li!= "" :
        print (li[i])
    i=i+1

print ("Val of i :",i)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if we want to count number of elements in a list without actually just calling `len` this could be done like this.

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "string1", "string2"]

print("Test of List")

i = 0
try:
    while True:
        li[i]
        i += 1
except IndexError:
    print('Length of the list:', i)
```

This is much slower, terribly obtuse and generally bad, but it works. I'd use `len(li)`

Answer (score 0):

I think using for loop will be more efficient and simple

```
for element in li:
    print("The value of i: ", i)
```

But for your while loop it produces an error because while loop does not have a true condition to stop, try using

```
While i < len(li) :
  if i != "" :
      print(' The value of i', i) 
  else:
      print (' empty element ') 
  i=+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "string1", "string2"]

print ("Test of List")

i = 0

while (i < len(li)):
    if(li[i] != ""):
        print (li[i])
    i = i + 1

print ("Val of i :", i )
```

The reason for this is because your while statement is wrong. 
Try it

And If you still like your logic, Try it

```
def checkValiable(array, i):

    while (array[i] != ""):
        print (li[i])
        i = i + 1

    if(i < len(array) - 1):
        del array[i];
        checkValiable(array, i - 1)
        return

    print ("Val of i :", i)
    return array

li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,"", "string1", "string2"]


print ("Test of List")

i = 0
li.append("")

checkValiable(li, i)
```

Comment: Directly accessing `__magic__` attributes is bad style - you should use `len(li)` instead. But the proper solution is to use a `for` loop anyway.

Comment: Ok, i corrected it. __len__()  works for me so I did not care about that

Comment: Can you explain why it is bad style. @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: `__magic__` attributes and methods are used to implement (or override) operators or operator-like generic functions (like `len()` for example),  so they are actually implementation details, not part of the class public API.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much